# How can I use my Raspberry Pi for distributed building?

Tags: networking, server

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian whose processing power I'd like to harness to speed up the C++ build times in Visual Studio on my Windows 7 laptop with x86-64 architecture.

Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it might be, in practice no.

How would the work be split up and sent to the Pis?

Most modern machines will be a lot faster than the Pi as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could make sense to use the Raspberry Pi if you develop for the Raspberry Pi(arm-architecture). But I guess you like to develop an application which should run on a x86 and or x64(x86-64) system. The problem is if you split the work (let the Pi generate some compiled object files (.o)), then there is still the problem that your Pi has to emulate the 32/64 bit architecture (much performance loss).

And your second problem would be how do you decide which files should be generated by the laptop and the pi and how do you merge them again? The best way would be to use some networking for that.

I think you see that is much more time effort to get all this things solved as you would take to compile it just with your laptop (could be even slower).

(If you like the idea of remote developing you can check this out https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh )